# box2d - distance joint - minimal distance

Tags: box2d

Does any one know how to disable minimal distance in the distance join in box2d?

I am using it for my crane, as a rope/line where I can change length on the runtime, but sometimes it acts really weird because of minimal distance between anchor points.

Comment: There is a rope joint to do this.

Comment: Well I have been reading and indeed found that rope joint does not enforce minimal distance, but the only "options" this joint type got is "maxLength", there are no frequencyHz, dampingRatio for example. Thanks for answer.